# How to query the names of encrypted stored procedures?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

What query will identify the names of stored procedures which are encrypted?  Here's what I got so far -

```
select ROUTINE_NAME
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
where ROUTINE_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE'
-- need another condition here to identify just the encrypted SPROC's
order by ROUTINE_NAME asc
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
SELECT name FROM sys.procedures
WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY([object_id], 'IsEncrypted') = 1;
```

Comment: (And here's why I prefer `sys.<whatever>` over `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.<whatever>` - https://sqlblog.org/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information_schema-views

Comment: Great article.  Very informative.

Answer (score 3):

```
select ROUTINE_NAME
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
where ROUTINE_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE'
and ROUTINE_DEFINITION is null
order by ROUTINE_NAME asc
```

An encrypted Stored Procedure will have a `NULL` ROUTINE_DEFINITION.

Comment: That seems to be an implicit assumption - are you sure that's the only case? I prefer to trust `OBJECTPROPERTY` since that's explicit.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Straight from BOL: "Returns the first 4000 characters of the definition text of the function or stored procedure if the function or stored procedure is not encrypted. Otherwise, returns NULL."

Comment: But don't you consider it possible that there may be cases in the future where definition is NULL for other reasons? Also what does the ROUTINES view return for CLR procedures?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Absolutely, and good point.  +1 to your answer, I think that's the best approach as well.

Comment: Thanks, I think they're equally valid today, I just think the catalog views and objectproperty are more future-proof. :-)

Comment: @Aaron: I thought it's the other way around. You could use `sysobjects` in your answer :-))